# Residue theorem (complex analysis), why not for a function undefined on disks?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

Why is it that we can't apply the residue theorem $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum_nres(f,c_n).ind(\gamma,c_n)$ with $f$ non defined on several disks of center $c_n$, and that we can only do it with $f$ non defined on the points $c_n$ themselves?

I mean, if  $\int_\gamma f(z)dz = 2\pi i.res(f,c).ind(\gamma,c)$ is correct on an open ring of center $c$, can't we just see the integral on a domain missing several disks as the addition of integrals on rings homotopic to some sub-domains (covering the full domain altogether) around each of those disks?

Answer (score 2):

### Conceptual answer

Think about how we prove the Residue Theorem. Typical proofs work by splitting $\gamma$ into a sum of curves around each singularity, then applying results like Cauchy's Theorem and Cauchy Integral Formula to individual terms in a Laurent series. The proof of Cauchy Integral Formula basically comes down to shrinking the curve $\gamma$ to a smaller and smaller neighborhood of the singularity.

If your function is only defined via a Laurent series that converges on some annulus that isn't a punctured disc, then these proofs will fail at the "curve shrinking" step.

Alternatively, many (most) would probably say that the proofs fall apart before that step: it doesn't really make sense to define "residues" or decide which type of singularity we're looking at if all we have is a Laurent series that converges on a non-punctured-disc annulus. To see why we run into problems if we try to define and use those concepts on larger annuli, here's an.....

### Explicit example

Check out this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973583/1127272). It gives an explicit example using two different Laurent series for $f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-1)^2}$. If you (incorrectly) reason from the Laurent series that converges on $|z-1|>1$, then you'll end up concluding the residue at $z=1$ is 0. If you (correctly) use the Laurent series that converges on $0 < |z-1| < 1$, then you'll find that the true residue is -1. These don't match, so using the bigger annulus would get you the wrong answer.